# problema con la librería html2pdf en servidor web 000webhost

Tags: php, pdf, hosting, html2pdf

les comento el problema que tengo. estoy utilizando la libreria de **HTML2PDF** para el desarrollo de un sistema, en local me funciona perfectamente pero lo subi al hosting de 000webhost tal cual como lo tengo en el directorio local (xampp) y me sale el siguiente error. [image: Error que me genera al intentar mostrar el pdf]

este es el codigo que utilizo:

```
    <?php

    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
    include_once('../../conexion.php');
     $id_factura=$_REQUEST['fact'];
    
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;
    
    try {
        ob_start();
        include dirname(__FILE__).'/generarFactura.php';
        $content = ob_get_clean();
    
        $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A5', 'fr', true, 'UTF-8', 3);
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
        $html2pdf->output('Surtiplast-'.$id_factura.'.pdf');
    } catch (Html2PdfException $e) {
        $html2pdf->clean();
    
        $formatter = new ExceptionFormatter($e);
        echo $formatter->getHtmlMessage();
    }
?>
```

como les comente tal cual en el directorio local funciona correctamente. espero me puedan ayudar! muchas gracias aca tambien les dejo como esta organizado el proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas veces por seguridad en los servidores no se permite ir hacia arriba en la jerarquía de directorios. Intenta poner debajo del nivel donde invocas tus carpetas con archivos a incluir.

Comment: No trabajo con esta empresa pero puede que se solucione cambiando el require_once por: require_once dirname(__FILE__) . './../../vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: gracias Alfabravo intente eso que me dijiste y aun asi el problema persiste no se que mas puede ser!